# keycloak dynamic client registration registration_client_uri docker hostname override

Tags: docker, nginx, keycloak

I have successfully created a client inside Keycloak using Dynamic Client Registration

The response body contains:

```
"registration_client_uri":"https://127.0.0.1:8443/auth/realms...",
```

This is because Keycloak is installed with Docker, and is fronted by NginX. I want to replace the IP address/port with the actual public hostname.

Where are the docs / configurations for this?

I started keycloak as follows:

```
docker run -itd --name keycloak \
  --restart unless-stopped \
  --env-file keycloak.env \
  -p 127.0.0.1:8443:8443 \
  --network keycloak \
  jboss/keycloak:11.0.0 \
  -Dkeycloak.profile=preview
```

And inside keycloak.env, I have set `KEYCLOAK_HOSTNAME=example.com`

Comment: If `registration_client_uri` should point at the same keycloak server you may try to specify URI without a host address. Just `/auth/realms...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure env variable `PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true`, because Keycloak is running behind Nginx reverse proxy - https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/

> Enabling proxy address forwarding
>
> When running Keycloak behind a proxy, you will need to enable proxy address forwarding.
>
> docker run -e PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true jboss/keycloak